# Mongodb - Finding a field value existence in another field

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to find all documents in a collection where documents with field (_id) values exist in another field (ex. parentID). Taking in consideration that both fields exist in the documents of the same collection? Thanks

```
Categories.find({'_id': 'parentID'})

{
   _id: 11,
   parentID: 1
}
```

I am using MongoDB 2.6.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is easy to do with the [`$where` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/).

```
db.Categories.find({'$where':"this._id === this.parent"})
```

This gives you more flexibility than your regular `find` syntax but be warned that MongoDB needs to evaluate the Javascript so this *is* slower than a regular query.